# How To Make Noise Signal After Estimate Noise Variance

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

For Blind Source Separation (Adapative Filtering , LMS Algorithm), i need two input. a)noisy signal, 2)noise signal. But How can i make the noise signal. If i can estimate the noise variance of noisy signal, then how can i make a noise signal from noise variance in matlab.  I am new in signal processing.

Comment: You can generate WGN with `randn()`.

Answer (score 1):

try this (matlab):

noise = normrnd(mean ,sqrt(variance) ,rows ,columns);

it will generate random numbers from the normal distribution (mean,variance).
rows and columns will dictate the result matrix dimensions.